# Weird Mathematica Plot behavior

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When running the command:

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 10}]
```

I get very weird output:
[image]

Not only that, but when running

```
Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 1000}, Mesh -> All]
```

Which should mark the points it generated the lines between, gives me this:
[image]

Please note that its `1000` here - not `10`.

After reading Mathematica's explanation about `Plot` - it says that it generates more points if the function changes fast. The function `1/x` is changing very slow - and I though that Mathematica isn't generation enough points - but using `Mesh -> All` I showed that it is incorrect.

Did anyone encounter this weird behavior? Can anyone please explain to me what causes this, and how can it be fixed?

P.S: This isn't the only function which gives bad output - its actually quite common.

P.P.S: I tried playing with `MaxRecursion` and `WorkingPresicion` - and it did not help.

Edit: I've just notices that the X axis isn't 0 - if you look at the first graph, you will see `0.4` as the last number, and `0.6` above it. The X axis is actually `0.2`! So maybe the question is: why is the X axis at `0.2` and not `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any weirdness in your first plot, I see the graph of a hyperbola. Mathematica has even been kind enough to you to ignore your attempt to evaluate `1/0`.

In your second plot, I think that you are expecting Mathematica to draw 1000 points along the line it plots ?  How many pixels have you given it in which to draw those 1000 points in the x-direction ?  I think that what you are seeing is an artefact common to most computer-based drawings: ask for 1000 points across (perhaps) 250 pixels and something's got to give.  Or perhaps I don't understand why you are concerned about the output.

Finally, you ask: *why is the X axis at 0.2 and not 0*

The answer is that Mathematica has decided that the graph will look good that way.  If you want to force the x-axis to cross the y-axis at 0, use the `AxesOrigin` option in your `Plot` command.

Comment: At first I though that the X plane IS 0 - so it was very weird that the graph passed it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, mma is just trying to be kind. If you enter `Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]` you will get the correct plot range, but since it's infinity (for the y axis), then the rest of the function is basically zero. So you would see an "empty" plot, which is even more non intuitive...

Answer (score 2):

You may find value in `DiscretePlot`:

```
DiscretePlot[1/x, {x, 0.5, 10, 0.2},
  PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or add option `Joined -> True` and get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]